# Filter data.table inside function with varying filter arguments and vectorised fifelse()

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, vectorization

**Task:** I have a large numeric `data.table` (columns 1:3 are character required for subsetting) inside a user defined function to perform analyses on the data.
Prior to downstream analysis within the function, I'd like use the function's parameters to pass values in to filter the `data.table`, or if no values are supplied for a given column filter then to use all rows.

However, difficulty arises as not all column filters will be used all of the time.

Currently, my approach has been to use separate blocks of `if` `else` statements to filter to get a list of IDs for each column, which I then `intersect`, before using this to subset the `data.table`. The example included states 3 columns, but there are more in the actual data which makes this approach clunky and inefficient (although it works).

**Query:** Is there a method to filter `data.table` directly, given that it is unknown which filtered columns will be used? Or, is there a way to vectorise the process with `ifelse()` or `fifelse()`?
I'd even take help with embedding it in a `for` loop, but for that to work I'd need to dynamically create variable names to store each ID list.

*I'd like to keep the solution to using `data.table` and `base` functions. Also, the function's parameter names can be changed to be the same as the column names of the `data.table` if that makes coding and readability easier.*

I appreciate any help offered.

**Data:**

```r
# Install data.table package if not installed and load
if (!require("data.table")) {
  install.packages("data.table")
  library(data.table)
}

# Data (example)
head(DT, n=2)

#>     ID     info1  info2  name1  name2  name3  name4
#>     <char> <char> <char> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1:  A100   StuffA StuffX 0.1460 NA     -0.019 0.2102
#> 2:  A101   StuffA StuffY 0.0987 -1.307 -0.174 NA
```

**Current method:**

```r
# Function (example)
myfunc <- function(ID_filter = "", info1_filter = "", info2_filter = "") {

  # Get IDs to use as filter
  if (ID_filter != "") {
    ID_list <- DT[ID %in% ID_filter][["ID"]]
  } else {
    ID_list <- DT[["ID"]]
  }
  
  if (info1_filter != "") {
    info1_list <- DT[info1 %in% info1_filter][["info1"]]
  } else {
    info1_list <- DT[["info1"]]
  }

  # Get overall filter list
  filters <- Reduce(intersect, list(ID, info1, info2))

  # Subset data.table
  DT <- DT[ID %in% filters]  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function could be simplified with

```
myfunc <- function(DT, ID_filter = "", info1_filter = "", info2_filter = "") {

 lst1 <- Filter(function(x) all(x != ""), 
     dplyr::lst(ID_filter, info1_filter, info2_filter))
 if(length(lst1) > 0 ) {
      pat <- paste(sub("_filter", "", names(lst1)), collapse="|")     
      i1 <- DT[, Reduce(`&`, Map(`%in%`, .SD, lst1)), .SDcols = patterns(pat)]
      DT[i1]
 } else DT
 
 }
```

-testing

```
setDT(DT)
myfunc(DT, ID_filter = "A100")
#     ID  info1  info2 name1 name2  name3  name4
#1: A100 StuffA StuffX 0.146    NA -0.019 0.2102
myfunc(DT, ID_filter = "A100", info1 = "StuffA")
#     ID  info1  info2 name1 name2  name3  name4
#1: A100 StuffA StuffX 0.146    NA -0.019 0.2102
myfunc(DT, ID_filter = "A100", info1 = "StuffA", info2 = "StuffX")
#     ID  info1  info2 name1 name2  name3  name4
#1: A100 StuffA StuffX 0.146    NA -0.019 0.2102

myfunc(DT, ID_filter = "A100", info1 = "StuffA", info2 = "StuffY")
#Empty data.table (0 rows and 7 cols): ID,info1,info2,name1,name2,name3...

myfunc(DT) # if all the parameters are "", return the full data
#     ID  info1  info2  name1  name2  name3  name4
#1: A100 StuffA StuffX 0.1460     NA -0.019 0.2102
#2: A101 StuffA StuffY 0.0987 -1.307 -0.174     NA
```

#### data

```
DT <- structure(list(ID = c("A100", "A101"), info1 = c("StuffA", "StuffA"
), info2 = c("StuffX", "StuffY"), name1 = c(0.146, 0.0987), name2 = c(NA, 
-1.307), name3 = c(-0.019, -0.174), name4 = c(0.2102, NA)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort @akrun, I appreciate it. I'm trying to follow your code, but I'm unable to find information on the ```dplyr``` function ```lst``` (also, I'd prefer to not use an additional library, is there an alternative?) Is the purpose of the ```pat <- paste(sub(...))``` line to process the parameter names to match the column names? If it is, then if I change the parameter names to be identical to the column names could I just use ```pat <- names(lst1)```?

Comment: @BuzzB It is just to construct a named list with `lst`.  with base R, you can do `list(ID_filter = ID_filter, info1_filter =  info1_filter, info2_filter =  info2_filter)` that replace the line

Comment: @BuzzB It is just that your input have `_filter`.  So either name the list as `list( ID = ID_filter, info1 = info_filter,...`  and then use `pat <- paste(names(lst1), collapse="|")`

Comment: Thanks again @akrun . Unfortunately this code does not work when multiple values are supplied for a given column filter e.g. ```info2_filter = c("StuffX", "StuffY")```, which is unlike my original work. How could your code be extended to maintain this functionality?

Comment: Thanks @akrun , it works great. The only issue is that although it is more concise, it performs slower than the version I had implemented. Is there a cross-platform parallel version of ```Map()``` that might improve it? Meanwhile, I've attempted to refine my previous approach but I have become stuck: ```filter_list <- list(ID = ID, info1 = info1, ...)```; ```filter_if <- lapply(filter_list, function(x) if(x=="") DT[["ID"]] else DT[names(x) %in% x][["ID"]])```. ```View(filter_list)``` and ```View(filter_if)``` reveals some clues as to the problem, but don't know how to resolve it.